# Quiver representation shorthand

Tags: xy-pic

Consider the quiver `\xymatrix{ 1 \ar[r] &2 \ar[r] &3 \ar[r] &4}`. The projective representation P(1) is `\xymatrix{ k \ar[r] &k \ar[r] &k \ar[r] &k}`.

I would like to use the shorthand notation for this representation i.e. 1 2 3 4 written vertically. I don't know how to do this in LaTeX.

Also, I'm not looking for a matrix here because there can be a more complicated notation, for example something like the following:

[image: shorthand]

where the values are not always perfectly vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Any shorthand notation will rely on a better understanding of the necessary flexibility, but the brute force approach is nearly trivial to begin with.

Here I show various positions relative to the baseline.

EDITED to reduce vertical stacking gap, based on comment from OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{.75\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
Either this,
\tabbedCenterstack{&3&&5\\2&&4&\\1&&&},
or this,
\tabbedLongstack{&3&&5\\2&&4&\\1&&&},
or this,
\tabbedLongunderstack{&3&&5\\2&&4&\\1&&&}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Is there any way to reduce the default vertical spacing between rows?

Comment: @bluedusk  `\setstackgap{L}{.8\baselineskip}` or some other suitable value would do it.  This can be set in the preamble, for example.